# Calculating distance between points from table of UIDs [ArcMap]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, coordinates, dbf

I have a .dbf file containing pairs of point feature Unique Identifiers (UIDs), and need to calculate the straight-line distance between each of these pairs.

The XY coordinates of the individual points are part of a separate feature class (also containing the UIDs).

Is there any way that I could calculate the distance between these points without having to create a new table of XY coordinate values? (There are 3085 pairs altogether, so this would be impractical)

EDIT:

.dbf example:
UID0        UID1
40598473    83894847
40638728    59068967
38989786    49872793

Point feature attribute table example:
UID        X        Y
38989768    425667    346273
40598473    425668    346277
40638728    425598    346256

Comment: can you please add an example of what you see in your table?

Comment: have you joined the tables based on the UID?

Comment: No point joining tables based upon UIDs considering the repetition in the pairs (multiple pairs contain same point features). Externally attributing the XY-coords was quicker despite issues with adding Excel-edited files to ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up thinking about this problem via the GIS route and turned to Excel.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915215/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-then-get-the-value-of-the-next) answer provided me with what I needed (it uses Excel's VLOOKUP function to search the UIDs to find one that matches those in the pairs and returns their X and Y coordinates). If anyone wants a more specific explanation, I'll be happy to give it!